# Force the user to pick option 1 before option 2

Tags: java

I want to force the user to select choice 1 before they can proceed and select choice 2 any help would appreciated. 
(note I've only done if,switch,while,for,do....while,methods and arrays in java so far)

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);   

int[] ages = new int[3];
int choice;
do {
   System.out.println("Average Age program");
   System.out.println("Enter 1 to enter ages");
   System.out.println("Enter 2 to calculate the average Age");
   System.out.println("Enter 0 to Exit");
   choice = sc.nextInt();
   switch(choice) {
       case 1:
           acceptAges(ages);
           break;

       case 2:
           averageAge(ages);
           break;

       default:
           System.out.print("invalid option");

    } 

  } while(choice != 0);
}
```

Comment: It is possible, but I think it is better to maintain the logic flow

Answer (score 0):

You could simply not display choice `2` until `1` was chosen at least once.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);   

 int[] ages = new int[3];
 int choice;
 boolean is2Enabled=false,
 do{
   System.out.println("Average Age program");
   System.out.println("Enter 1 to enter ages");
   if(is2Enabled)
     System.out.println("Enter 2 to calculate the average Age");
   System.out.println("Enter 0 to Exit");
   choice=sc.nextInt();
   switch(choice)       
   {
       case 1:
       acceptAges(ages);
       is2Enabled=true;
       break;

       case 2:
       if(is2Enabled)
         averageAge(ages);
       else
         System.out.print("invalid option");
       break;

       default:
       System.out.print("invalid option");
    } 
  }while(choice != 0);
}
```